# Magento: Creating custom pages with multiple levels in the url

Tags: magento

I've been creating pages using a custom module, having the following to designate a url:

```
 <frontend>
        <routers>
          <materials>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Modulename_Custom</module>
                    <frontName>materials</frontName>
                </args>
            </materials>
            <materials_wood>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Modulename_Custom</module>
                    <frontName>materials/wood</frontName>
                </args>
            </materials_wood>
        </routers>

</frontend>
```

I want to have different levels in the url, so www.example.com/materials/ and www.example.com/materials/wood/
Of course, the above example doesn't work.

Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: Don't you have in the Admin Menu: CMS > Pages > Manage Hierarchy? (maybe it's an Enterprise feature) Otherwise maybe you can use Categories?

Comment: Thats' an enterprise only feature :)

Comment: I do have enterprise. So I can create it in this admin even though it's a custom module?

Comment: What are content of these pages supposed to be? You can build this structure with normal CMS pages. Just put material/wood in the URL-key field. Then content of CMS will be displayed when you visit: www.example.com/materials/wood/

Comment: I want to do it as a module so I can track it using git